# When to use x3::lit in Boost spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit-x3

I am beginning with Boost Spirit x3 parsing library - and I'm very excited about it.

One thing unclear to me is when and why one should use `x3::lit`.

From what I understood, it's because we can not expect an expression like `']' >> double_` to be interpreted as intended within C++ syntactic rules.

But my interpretation seems incorrect, since the official documentation displays numerous examples of simple strings followed by the `>>` operator, and others instances where parenthesis and/or brackets have to be specified as `lit(']')`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not *generally* expect `'[' >> x` to see the X3 expression overload.

Overload resolution depends on the types of both operands. Since `'[`' is char, there cannot be user-defined overloads. So in this case, **only** if `x` is already an x3 parser expression the x3 overload of `operator>>` will be found.

In generic code, if both operands are unknown you should use `x3::as_parser` instead of `x3::lit` because it will leave other types of expressions intact, but promotes string literals like you would expect:

```
 auto combine(auto a, auto b) {
      return x3::as_parser(a) >> x3::as_parser(b);
 }
```

The mechanism for overload resolution at play in e.g. `'x' >> x3::double_` is  ADL: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl (Incidentally it's the same mechanism that makes `std::cout << "Hello world\n"` find the `std::operator>>` overload)

Comment: Wahoo super clear thank you @sehe!
If the code compiles, it means that the overload resolution worked as expected, right? Meaning  I can expect the compiler to hint me about using `lit` or `as_parser` ?

Comment: Yes in practice. Of course in perfidious scenarios you can imagine foreign overloads interfering in a way that generates valid parser expressions with unexpected meaning, but I can't see that happening unless you do it on purpose.